# Comando 'curl localhost' retornando 'curl: (52) Empty reply from server'

Tags: libcurl, docker

Boa tarde!

Segue uma descrição do cenário:
Estou utilizando o laptop corporativo, quando executo o mesmo comando sem estar logado na VPN ele retorna a página do container que criei para teste:

```
docker container run -d -p 80:80 nginx
```

Porém após logar na VPN e executar o mesmo comando recebo a mensagem citada.

Obs: As variáveis de ambiente proxy, http_proxy estão setadas como vazio ''